# Проблемы с русской кодировкой при извлечении заголовков в Gmail

Tags: php, utf-8, imap, gmail

При выводе заголовков входящих сообщений с русскими заголовками выводит вот примерно такое "=?UTF-8?Q?1_=D0=BD=D0=BE=" вот пытаюсь таким образом извлечь заголовки:

```
$headers = imap_headers($mbox);

    if ($headers == false) {
        echo "Call failed<br />\n";
    } else {
        foreach ($headers as $val) {
            echo  iconv('UTF-7', 'UTF-8', $val). "<br />\n";
        }
    }
```

Перекодировка из UTF-7 вроде как должна была решить эту проблему но не решила. Может кто знает в чем дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией для декодирования заголовков [imap_mime_header_decode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php)

Пример

```
<?php
$text = "=?utf-8?B?0JvQuNGH0L3Ri9C5INC60LDQsdC40L3QtdGCINC90LDQu9C+0LPQvtC/0LvQsNGC0LXQu9GM0YnQuNC60LA=?=
    =?utf-8?B?OiDQmNC30LzQtdC90LXQvdC40LUg0YHQstC10LTQtdC90LjQuSDQvtCxINC+0LHRitC10LrRgtC1?=";

$elements = imap_mime_header_decode($text);
for ($i=0; $i<count($elements); $i++) {
    echo "Charset: {$elements[$i]->charset}\n";
    echo "Text: {$elements[$i]->text}\n\n";
}
```

Результат

```
Charset: utf-8
Text: Личный кабинет налогоплательщика

Charset: utf-8
Text: : Изменение сведений об объекте
```

Comment: извините может что делаю не так но опять не выводит вот по Вашему примеру: 
`private function decode($text){
        $elements = imap_mime_header_decode($text);
        for ($i=0; $i<count($elements); $i++) {
            echo "Charset: {$elements[$i]->charset}\n";
            echo "Text: {$elements[$i]->text}\n";
        }
    }`
Применяю:
`$headers = imap_headers($mbox);

        if ($headers == false) {
            echo "Call failed<br />\n";
        } else {
            foreach ($headers as $val) {
               $this->decode($val);
            }
        }`

Comment: @vexel, в логе ошибок сервера ошибки присутствуют?

Comment: ошибок нет, выводит это:
`Charset: default` 
`Text: =?UTF-8?B?0J7RgtGH0LXRgiD` 
Ваш текст у меня тоже переводит, а этот нет

Comment: @vexel, у вас почему-то формат кодирования нарушен. На конце кодированной строки должено быть два символа `?=`. Если вместо `=?UTF-8?B?0J7RgtGH0LXRgiD` подавать `=?UTF-8?B?0J7RgtGH0LXRgiD?=`, то отработает нормально.

Comment: точно подметили у меня тему сообщения почему то извлекает в таком виде  `' =?UTF-8?B?0JTQsNC50LTQttC (21896 chars)'` Ваш метод прекрасно работает, это у меня почему-то не все символы показывает, пользовался оф. документацией php, не подскажите что может быть не так?

Comment: @vexel, видимо функция imap_headers() выдает не то, что вы ожидали. Вот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/q/38697699/5441700 в котором видно, что в возвращаемых данных в одном элементе собраны и дата письма, и имя пользователя, и тема, и размер письма. Попробуйте функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-fetch-overview.php использовать

Answer (score 0):

вытаскивай заголовки **imap_headerinfo()** и потом **imap_mime_header_decode()**